# How to use an Ant script to start and stop Tomcat server?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, ant

I need to start and stop Tomcat server using Ant script, however I found a script on Stack Overflow but when I am using it, it is giving below mentioned error.

The script and the message on console I am getting is mentioned below :

```
<project name="sample">
<property name="name" value="sample"/>
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath"> 
<fileset dir="C:\Users\vivsharm\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.64-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\lib"> 
<include name="catalina-ant.jar"/> 
</fileset> 
</path> 
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask"> 
<classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/> 
</taskdef>

<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
<classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
<start url="http://localhost:8080/"
username="uname"
password="pwd"/>
</target>
<target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
<stop url="http://localhost:8080/"
username="uname"
password="pwd"/>
</target>
</project>
```

and the error message I am getting is below :

```
C:\StartAndStopTomcat>ant start
Buildfile: C:\StartAndStopTomcat\build.xml

start:

BUILD FAILED
C:\StartAndStopTomcat\build.xml:19: Must specify 'path' attribute

Total time: 0 seconds

C:\StartAndStopTomcat>ant stop
Buildfile: C:\StartAndStopTomcat\build.xml

stop:

BUILD FAILED
C:\StartAndStopTomcat\build.xml:24: Must specify 'path' attribute

Total time: 0 seconds

    enter code here

C:\StartAndStopTomcat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Our build script is quite old, so there can be better ways to do that, but we use

```
<property name="tomcat.bin.dir" location="${tomcat.catalina_home}/bin" />
<property name="tomcat.startup.file" location="${tomcat.bin.dir}/startup${os.script_extension}" />
...
<target name="tom-start" description="start tomcat server">
    <echo message="starting ${tomcat.catalina_base}" />
    <exec executable="${os.command_interpreter}">
        <arg line="${os.command_interpreter.mandatory_argument}" />
        <arg line="${tomcat.startup.file}" />
        <env key="CATALINA_BASE" value="${tomcat.catalina_base}" />
        <env key="JAVA_HOME" value="${javac.jdk.dir}" />
        <env key="JRE_HOME"  value="${javac.jdk.dir}" />
        <env key="JAVA_OPTS" value="${JAVA_OPTS}" />
    </exec>
</target>
<target name="tom-shut" description="stop tomcat server (remember that it might not shut down immediately)">
    <echo message="shutting down ${tomcat.catalina_base}" />
    <exec executable="${os.command_interpreter}">
        <arg line="${os.command_interpreter.mandatory_argument}" />
        <arg line="${tomcat.shutdown.file}" />
        <env key="CATALINA_BASE" value="${tomcat.catalina_base}" />
        <env key="JAVA_HOME" value="${javac.jdk.dir}" />
        <env key="JRE_HOME"  value="${javac.jdk.dir}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

The `os.command_interpreter` is either `/bin/bash` on linux machines, or `C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe` for Windows machines. Of course you need to pre-set also `tomcat.catalina_home` and other properties.